# zlib.net code example for C# that take byte[] as input agument

Tags: c#, vb6-migration

I spent 3 hours searching for how to uncompress a string using Zlib.net.dll and I did not find anything useful.

Since my string is compressed by the old VB6 program that uses zlib.dll and I do not want to use file access each time I want to uncompress a string.

The problem is you need to know what the original size of the byte[] is before compression.
Or you can use dynamic array for decoding the data.

The code is here:

```
    private string ZlibNetDecompress(string iCompressData, uint OriginalSize)
    {
        byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(iCompressData);
        byte[] lDecodeData = new byte[OriginalSize];
        string lTempoString = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(todecode_byte);
        todecode_byte = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(lTempoString);
        string lReVal = "";
        MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream InStream = new MemoryStream(todecode_byte);
        zlib.ZOutputStream outZStream = new zlib.ZOutputStream(outStream);
        try
        {
            CopyStream(InStream, outZStream);
            lDecodeData = outStream.GetBuffer();
            lReVal = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(lDecodeData);
        }

        finally
        {
            outZStream.Close();
            InStream.Close();
        }
        return lReVal;
    }

    private void CopyStream(System.IO.Stream input, System.IO.Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2000];
        int len;
        while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, 2000)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        output.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: **What is your question exactly?**

Answer (score 0):

You could use  the GZipStreamClass from the framework.

```
var data = new byte[resultSizeMax];
using (Stream ds = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress)) 
  for (var i=0; i< 1000; i+=ds.Read(data, i,1000-i);
```